# How to detect dark mode in email clients such as GMail?

Tags: css, html-email

I am in the process of designing an automated email. It is mostly text, but what gives me trouble is the use of a logo.

The logo is a black text (unusual font, so can't be text, must be an image) on white background. I  could also make the background transparent, but that would still leave me with a problem.

In many email clients that looks fine, but of course there are "dark mode" apps, such as GMail for Android, depending on system settings. The logo now of course looks bad, because of the white box on an otherwise dark background. (If the background of the image was transparent, it would now be black on darkgray, which would be bad too).

On a normal website, `<style>@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { ... }</style>` would do the trick, but here's the catch:

I was trying to simply use the media query to detect dark mode, but according to [this table on mailchimp.com](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/), neither `link`, nor `style` elements are supported anywhere in emails displayed in GMail.

Is there any way to detect the users dark-mode choice to replace the logo?

(I tried to make the background of the email white to match the logo, but that simply was replaced by all black by GMail)

Comment: If nothing changed in the last year, then unfortunately it does answer it.

Comment: You cannot replace the logo in Gmail, as it does not regard `prefers-color-scheme`, however, you can make the logo have a white stroke, or a white blur behind it, and save it as PNG24, so that it will be seen on dark modes/themes. If that's what you want, we can change the question title and comments so that I can answer properly (after being reopened)